# Create a team of 11 players out of 22 players from two teams

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and I am trying to create a solution for a statement.

1. There are two teams playing a game against each other.
2. Each team has 11 players, so there are total 22 players.
3. Out of 22 players need to select only 11 players.
4. Now out of selected 11 players one can be captain and one can be
   vice-captain.

We can read players name from excel.

Solution is to input all the 22 players name and display all the teams (11 players) with captain and vice-captain.

Here I am able to generate the random team out of 22 players but above mentioned constraints are getting matched.

```
import random

def get_random_player(players):
    return players.pop(random.randrange(len(players)))

team_1 = []
players = ["Rahul","Virat","Sachin","King"] //22 players

for x in range(len(players) // 2):
   team_1.append(get_random_player(players))


print(team_1)
```

Example :

```
Team 1 :
Team1_Palyer1
Team1_Palyer2
Team1_Palyer3
Team1_Palyer4
Team1_Palyer5
Team1_Palyer6
Team1_Palyer7
Team1_Palyer8
Team1_Palyer9
Team1_Palyer10
Team1_Palyer11


Team 2 :
Team2_Palyer1
Team2_Palyer2
Team2_Palyer3
Team2_Palyer4
Team2_Palyer5
Team2_Palyer6
Team2_Palyer7
Team2_Palyer8
Team2_Palyer9
Team2_Palyer10
Team2_Palyer11

Output :

Team1_Palyer1
Team2_Palyer1
Team1_Palyer3(c)
Team2_Palyer5
Team1_Palyer5
Team2_Palyer6
Team2_Palyer7(vc)
Team1_Palyer4
Team2_Palyer9
Team2_Palyer10
Team1_Palyer10
```

Here we have 5 plyers from Team 1 and 6 players from Team 2
Made Team1_Palyer3 as captain and Team2_Palyer7 as vice-captain.

Need to display all the teams which can be created.

Comment: please include your code

Comment: What is your specific question or problem?

Comment: But what dos you want? You just want to get a random team with captan and vicecaptan? that is easy, just use This: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/randomly-select-elements-from-list-without-repetition-in-python/amp/ you need to use it two times, one to choose members and another to choose captan+vicecaptan

Comment: "Need to display all the teams which can be created." what you mean?

Comment: to be more precise if you wanted all the teams there will be total teams created `705432`  calculated by combination formula `nCr ` (i.e 22C11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to create how many 11 players Team can be created from 22 players.
you can use the formula of ***combinations*** how many team will be created

```
22C11 = 22! / (11! * (22-11)!) = 705,432
```

Total teams will be generated **705,432**

**Code:**

```
import itertools

players = ['Team1_Player1', 'Team1_Player2', 'Team1_Player3', 'Team1_Player4', 'Team1_Player5', 'Team1_Player6', 'Team1_Player7', 'Team1_Player8', 'Team1_Player9', 'Team1_Player10', 'Team1_Player11', 'Team2_Player1', 'Team2_Player2', 'Team2_Player3', 'Team2_Player4', 'Team2_Player5', 'Team2_Player6', 'Team2_Player7', 'Team2_Player8', 'Team2_Player9', 'Team2_Player10', 'Team2_Player11']

team_combinations=list(itertools.combinations(players, 11))
print(len(team_combinations)) #705432

#To print the team.
"""
for i,team in enumerate(team_combinations, start=1):
    print(f"Team {i}:")
    for player in team:
        print(player)
"""
```

**Note** Just not cleared how you created **captain** and **vice captain** of your team hence it is missing.